# For loops: Reverse if-statements or continue checks?

Tags: performance, loops, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

I am trying to find the most efficient way to loop through for loops
Say I want to loop through something and check if it's null, should I then use `if(object == null) { continue }` 
or should I use
`if(object != null) { // code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bunch of test runs with arrays and lists of objects of the size of 100,000 to 100,000,000. It's safe to say that these methods of doing it is the same. Both of the methods took the same amount of time (Being about 2-5 ms apart) so there is visibly no difference when the first one takes 4252 milliseconds and the other one takes 4254 milliseconds.